# Is there a network protocol specification or description outside the source code?

Tags: protocol, network

Obviously the network protocol is specified in the Monero source code in c++, but I was wondering if a more generic document exists that could be useful for implementing a program in another language that interacts directly with nodes on the network. Something along the lines of this, perhaps:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation

Or this:

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#block-chain

I realize both those documents explicitly state that they are NOT specifications, merely descriptions of the protocol as implemented the reference client, but I'm still curious if something like this exists for Monero/Bytecoin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but it's on the list of things we have to do. At this juncture it would be wasted on Monero, but once / if we switch the wire protocol to something standardised like ZMTP then it will be nearly trivial to do.